# How to connect to informix through Node.js using MongoDB driver?

Tags: node.js, informix

I read somewhere else on stack overflow that you can connect to an informix db on Node.js using the mongo db driver.

[How to connect Informix server using Node js with ODBC connectivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946845/how-to-connect-informix-server-using-node-js-with-odbc-connectivity)

However, the linked documentation was an invalid link and the author didn't elaborate on it. I was wondering if anyone knew how or if its even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to configure and start the Informix Wire Listener, an API translation application that will convert MongoDB API calls into SQL for Informix. It runs against newer Informix server (12.10.xC8 or higher, something like that in case you have too old of a server for it to work with).

Documentation for using it is at
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=compatibility-wire-listener

Comment: Is the mongo DB driver the only way to connect to informix dbs using javascript?

Comment: It's the only way when using javascript in the browser. If you are more thinking like NodeJS, you can try the NodeJS driver out on Github at https://github.com/OpenInformix/node-informixdb.